# Relationship en SQLAlchemy en python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

mi problema es que tengo una lista con producto comprados que deberían estar dentro de la tabla compra la cual esta adentro de la tabla cliente, esto que quiere decir, es que tengo un cliente que puede hacer muchas compras y esas compras tienes muchos elementos y como no se si se puede guardar una lista en SQLAlchemy cree otra tabla llamada producto_comprado y cada elemento de la lista es una tabla dejo como estan declaradas las tablas:

```
class Cliente( db ):
    __tablename__ = "cliente"

    id       = Column("id", Integer, primary_key = True )
    rut      = Column("rut", Integer, unique=True )
    nombre   = Column("nombre", String )
    apellido = Column("apellido", String )
    compra   = relationship('Compra')

class Compra( db ):
    __tablename__ = "compra"

    id        = Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True )
    cliente   = Column("cliente", Integer, ForeignKey('cliente.id'))
    total     = Column("total", Integer )
    productos = relationship('ProductoComprado')

class ProductoComprado( db ):
    __tablename__ = "productocomprado"

    id     = Column( Integer, primary_key=True )
    compra = Column( Integer, ForeignKey('compra.id'))
    nombre = Column( String )
    precio = Column( Integer )
```

y el codigo para guardar todo eso es este:

```
def Comprar():
    _id = 0
    precio_final = 0
    rut = -1
    pago = 0
    efectivo = 0
    vuelto = 0
    lista = []

    print ("\t .: Menu Comprar :. ")
    print ("Escribe -1 para salir ")
    while _id != -1:
        _id = input("  Escane el producto: ")
        producto = session.query( Producto ).filter_by( id = _id ).first()

        if producto is not None:
            precio_final = precio_final + producto.precio_final
            lista.append( producto )

    print ("\n  El precio final: %d " %  precio_final )
    rut = input("  Cual es el rut del cliente: ")
    cliente = session.query( Cliente ).filter_by( rut = rut ).first()
    if cliente is None:
        cliente = Cliente()
        cliente.rut = rut
        cliente.nombre = raw_input("  Cual es su nombre: ")
        cliente.apellido = raw_input("  Cual es su apellido: ")

        session.add( cliente )
        session.commit()

    pago = raw_input("  Con que metodo va a a pagar, efectivo o tarjeta [e/c]: ") 
    if pago == 'e' or pago == 'E':
        efectivo = input("  Con cuanto efectivo va a pagar: ")
        vuelto = efectivo - precio_final
        print ("  Su vuelto es: %d " % vuelto )
    else:
        print ("  Pagando con tarjeta.")

    compra = Compra()
    compra.total = precio_final
    compra.cliente = cliente

    session.add( compra )
    session.commit()

    for product in lista:
        producto_comprado = ProductoComprado()
        producto_comprado.nombre = product.nombre
        producto_comprado.precio = product.precio
        producto_comprado.compra = compra
        session.add( producto_comprado )
        session.commit()
```

Pero cuando llego a la parte de guardar me lansa el siguiente error y no que hacer para cambiarlo o si existe una manera de guardar una lista en SQLAlchemy. Gracias de antemano <3

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 174, in <module>
    Comprar()
  File "main.py", line 63, in LogInOut
    x = funcion()
  File "main.py", line 156, in Comprar
    session.commit()
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1008, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 487, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 466, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2424, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2562, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 67, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2522, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 416, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 583, in execute
    uow,
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
    insert,
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1063, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 974, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 273, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1093, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1234, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1452, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 296, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1230, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/frijolito/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 536, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table compra has no column named total [SQL: u'INSERT INTO compra (id, cliente, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (0, <__main__.Cliente object at 0x7fd2eaf4d550>, 2770)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: Debería ser `session.add( producto_comprado )` y no `Session.add( producto_comprado )`

Comment: @FJSevilla ya lo cambie y ahora me manda otro error mas grande que no se is pueda agregar en un comentario

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agregalo a ella.

Comment: ¿Añadiste el atributo/columna "table" después de crear la BD?

Comment: Cuando haces ```producto = session.query( Producto ).filter_by( id = _id ).first()``` no tienes ningún objeto que se llama Producto, deberías poner ProductoComprado entre los paréntesis.